# Referencing C++ library function causes a task to behave incorrectly

Tags: c++, linker, reference, task

I have a kernel project with C files, C libraries and C++ libraries as well.

When the project is built such that the main file (.c) has a reference to any function in one of those C++ libraries, the running system is damaged somehow, that is one of the tasks gets the CPU to 100% and never gives it up again.

All tasks are healthy (no HALTED, no SUSPENDED, no EXCEPTION) but that task blocks the overall system by allocating CPU.

That C++ library function is correctly called, can be debugged by breakpoints etc.

It seems that a side effect occurs when it is linked.

The problem is observed even if that C++ library function is just referenced, not even called.

There is no such a problem when using other C++ libraries.

How can you explain this and what points should I focus on?

Comment: Can you run it under valgrind?

Comment: Hmmm.. I hear valgrind thanx to you. http://valgrind.org/ My platform is INTEGRITY OS and PPC-32 (mpc8260), which seems to be NOT supported by valgrind. I am so sorry for not being able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your C++ libraries declaring their functions with the `extern "C"` construct? See this faq:

[(32.6) How can I create a C++ function f(int,char,float) that is callable by my C code?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6)

If you want the same C API header file to be usable by both C and C++, you can use the following commonplace trick:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif


// Function prototypes


#ifdef __cplusplus
} // Closes the extern "C" brace
#endif
```

---

There is no C++ runtime support in the kernel. Things like `new`, `delete`, and exceptions will not work. See this blog [article](http://pograph.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/porting-cpp-code-to-linux-kernel/) for tips on porting C++ code to the kernel.

Comment: Hi, for those C++ functions to be called by C functions, YES, they are declared as extern "C".

Comment: extern "C" is necessary for avoiding name mangling when using C/C++ together. However, please note that my problem has to do something with a deeper issue. I can call/user/debug C++ lib functions called by C functions. No problem.  A side affect is observed such that a task malfunctions for some reason after this linkage is performed.

Comment: Updated my answer with more stuff you probably already knew. :-)

Comment: Are there static objects in your C++ code? The kernel has no way of constructing them before your program runs.

Comment: If there are such static objects in that C++ library code, may it be responsible for such strange behavior ?

Comment: I don't know, really; I'm not a kernel developer. Just trying to provide some clues. I found this interesting article about using C++ in the kernel: http://kerneltrap.org/node/2067 It seems that this is quite a controversial topic! :-)